Error: Unable to find git in your PATH in flutter
when i run in powershell
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/tools/flutter-base-dir
gives me :
fatal: bad config line 11 in file C:/Users/akram/.gitconfig
what is the problem
flutter
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/tools/flutter-base-dir
fatal: bad config line 11 in file C:/Users/akram/.gitconfig

The message tells you exactly what's wrong. You used it in your title. Git is not on your system PATH. If it's not in the PATH, then git config cannot execute, because git can't be found. The words in the error message give you information, if you read them.

i put Git in the system variables and nothing happed
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
in the system variables

Looks like you don't have Git installed. You can install Git on your Windows by using this command in Powershell:
winget install -e --id Git.Git

Then add the directory C:\Program Files\Git\bin to your PATH.
You can either issue Git commands directly in Powershell or you can use Git-Bash which comes with the installation.

I did it but it gives me this
Found an existing package already installed. Trying to upgrade the installed package...
No available upgrade found.
No newer package versions are available from the configured sources.
then i run flutter gives me again this message
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Then you already have Git installed but you don't have the directory where the Git executable in your PATH environment variable. Please add C:\Program Files\Git\cmd to your PATH. If you don't know how to add a path to the PATH variable, do a search.

Have you added git path in your environment variables, you can try adding that, also the same question has been asked and answered in the post:
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH with FLUTTER
You can refer that, add the env variables and check again, if it still does not work, you can use the command
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/tools/flutter-base-dir
the bold part needs to be replaced with the location where your flutter directory is present.

do i put it in the user variables or in the system variables
note i put the dart sdk and flutter sdk in user variables

and i changed the bold part to flutter directory it shows me the same output
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Flutter
fatal: bad config line 11 in file C:/Users/akram/.gitconfig
